# Can't send app request, apparently sent but do not appear notifying users

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, apprequests

I'm having trouble getting users to forward the App request to his friends;

I'm using the next code in **client-side**:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'FBAPPD',
        frictionlessRequests: true,
        status     : true,
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true
    });
};
```

When the users selects her friends:

```
function sendRequestToRecipients() {
var user_ids = document.getElementById("request_ids").value; //ID_user1,ID_user2...
 FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'Prueba una nueva forma de comunicarte con tus contactos...',
        to: '' + user_ids + '',
    }, requestCallback);

function requestCallback(response) {
// Handle callback here
    if (response.request && response.to) 
    {
        var request_ids = [];
        for(i=0; i<response.to.length; i++) {
            var temp = response.request + '_' + response.to[i];
            request_ids.push(temp);
        }
        var requests = request_ids.join(',');
        $.post('/FB_Invitaciones', { uid: document.getElementById("FBUser").value, request_ids: requests }, function (resp) {
            // callback after storing the requests
        });
    } else 
    {
        alert('canceled');
    }
}
```

**Server Side**

```
<?php
[...]
    $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
        "client_id=" . $FBAPPID .
        "&client_secret=" . $FBSECRETFBAPPID .
        "&grant_type=client_credentials";

    $app_access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

    $user_id = $datos->getFBID();

    //Procesando ids 
    $ids = explode(",",$_REQUEST['request_ids']);

    foreach($ids as $request)
    {
        $apprequest_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/" .$request.
            "?".$app_access_token;
        $result = file_get_contents($apprequest_url);
    }
die()
?>
```

I can not find the error.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does the user see the pop-up, or does the error ocur after that? Is it eh Javascript side or the PHP side that's not working?

Comment: Apparently everything works correctly, I get the expected responses from Facebook (in server-side and client-side), but friends who have been invited not receive invitations.

I do not know if I need some method or something as I have not implemented.

Thanks for answering.

Comment: OK - sorry, can't help you with that as AppRequests is one bit of Facebook I've avoided. Could only help debugging the api/code bit.)

Comment: I'm found a solution in this question: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9054075/send-app-request-works-but-not-sent-to-user .In my case in the App Configuration I need check "App on Facebook" and now works fine.

Comment: Yes - you need to set your canvas URL in order for requests to go though.  When someone responds to a request - they get sent to the canvas URL - if none is supplied, the request it nullified because it wouldn't be able to redirect the new user anywhere... The canvas URL parameter is compulsory if you are implementing requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm found a solution in this question: 
[send app request works, but not sent to user?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9054075/send-app-request-works-but-not-sent-to-user) 
In my case in the App Configuration I need check "App on Facebook" and now works fine

Answer (score -1):

@gokuhs Copy past this and try this 1 is working perfectly ... change the design to your requirement also put your App id and secrot code
but from the retreiving part im having the problem... if anyone give a solution Im ready to pay even, I can give my ftp and facebook loging details

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['request_ids'])) {
    require_once('src/facebook.php');

    $config = array();
    $config["appId"] = "XXXXXXX";
    $config["secret"] = "XXXXXXX";
    $config["fileUpload"] = false; // optional

    // Create our Application instance.
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $config["appId"],
      'secret' => $config["secret"],
      'cookie' => true,
    ));

        echo $user_id= $facebook->getUser();

        // Here I want to retreive Type, color and message.

    }

    else{

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <title>Greetings</title>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div align="center"> </div>
    <div class="main">

    <div style="margin-left:300px; width:540px; margin:auto;">

    <table>
    <tr>
        <td height="39">
            <span style="font-size:18px;font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#603;">Type :</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="catag">
                <option>Love</option>
                <option>Friend</option>
                <option>Mother</option>
                <option>Father</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td height="56">
            <span style="font-size:18px;font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#603;">Color :</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="datas">
                <option>Red</option>
                <option>Yellow</option>
                <option>Blue</option>
                <option>Red</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <span style="font-size:18px;font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#603;">Greeting :</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea type="text" name="message" id="msg" style="height:40px; width:350px;" ></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" id="one" style="color:#CCC; background-color:#603; border:none; width:80px; height:40px;"
            onclick="sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector(); return false;"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>      

    <script>
      FB.init({
        appId  : 'XXXXXX',
        status : true,
        cookie : true,
        frictionlessRequests: true,
        oauth: true
      });


      function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {

        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: $("#msg").val(),
          data: $("#datas").val(),

        },function getMultipleRequests(requestIds) {
            FB.api('', {"ids": requestIds }, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
             });
        }, requestCallback);
      }  

      function requestCallback(response) {
        // Handle callback here
        //var requestID = FB.api("/requestID", callback);   
        alert("Post was published.");
      }
    </script>

    <div id="fb">

    </div>
    <?php }?>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: That is **way** to much code to post.  You are not giving any answer here - you are just giving the OP a different application... In any case (even with out reading all your code) I can tell you that this would not work - you are missing the `<div id=fb-root></div>` element in your markup... The JS SDK will have no place to embed itself...

Comment: @Lix ,Thanks for the Advise Bro.. But rite now I cant ask any questions. Do u kno what do I wanna do for that.. Please waiting for your reply... thanx again.

Comment: did you read the attached link to that message? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers

Comment: @Lix yeah I have checked. Now im trying to correct my answers. I dono if it is not work for me then absurd staying in stackoverflow. by the way Thanx Lix

Comment: No problem! :) [so] is very strict about what is allowed on the site.  You should read that link very carefully and understand *why* these limitations are enforced - once you do that it'll be easier for you to interact with people here...